# 2003 hyundai tiburon gt overheated

Tags: hyundai, overheating, no-crank-no-start, tiburon

I was driving down the interstate in top gear, just coasting about 80 to 85 mph (nothing) when it overheated.

The motor basically immediately shut itself down and now it's a no crank, no start.

Can someone throw a couple ideas of what might have happened?

Timing did not skip or loosen, and I'm thinking the head warped or bent a valve. Would it be easier to replace the motor, or tear it apart and rebuild it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you seized the engine. It *might* restart once completely cooled (many engines do), but that doesn't mean you haven't caused damage to it. Will most likely incur a rebuild with a lot of engine work, or possibly a new engine.

Comment: Is there Any specific part of the motor you think might have siezed up to cause this ?

Comment: Could it possibly by any chance be simple and be one of the head gaskets

Comment: The definition of "seized" is, the pistons/rings get so hot, they get stuck in the cylinder bore. They may/may not contract enough to come un-seized, but there is going to be permanent damage done.If it won't turn over and you have good battery power and the starter works (will spin) (did before, should now), your engine is most likely toast.

Comment: Ok i got the motor to turn manually behind the wheel finder so the motor is not seized

Comment: Thermostat was stuck and needs to be replaced and I believe the pressure build was cause from that and it cracked the radiator (also to be replaced) a nice pretty long cut across the too of it which is where the steam came from

Comment: When it overheated the car did not smoke once so ever and there's no water is the oil and the motor still has oil on the dipstick which is how I can determine water had no possible way of getting in the oil.  What can you determine with that information

Comment: Try and start it. I fit runs, it runs.

Comment: Getting it to turn over finally with key so that's good news it's getting fuel to the block and that this an the other is fine but it's just not wanting to crank... thinking possibly the computer has an issue ...everything is engaging fuel pump . Injectors ECT but still not firing up & timing is not off .... I'm stumped??

Comment: Is it throwing codes? Is your battery good? Are the starter or alternator covered in oil from the signature leaky valve cover gaskets? When you mention "head gaskets" I assume were talking about the v6. I've had 2. A rebuild is probably worth more than the entire vehicle. Don't know about the radiator price but you could do a lot better on craigslist for what those tibs are worth now.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the motor turns, that does not mean it hasn't seized as it could have been a soft seize, in which the rings do damage to the cylinder walls without getting stuck. There are three parts needed for combustion in an engine: fuel, spark, and compression. Fuel and spark aren't likely to have changed from overheating, but compression definitely could.

Do a compression test to start with, you should have definitely no less than 100psi compression, with all cylinders within about 15psi of each other. Most likely given the failure scenario, all cylinders will be low on compression.